# Using Select-Object and Where-Object in same sentence with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, select-object

I'm new using PowerShell, and I'm trying to select some fields from Active Directory that are like some strings, let me explain:

This is my code so far:

```
$csv = Import-Csv C:\Users\barreola\Desktop\test_AD.csv

$IS = @(
'*601*',
'*609*',
'*602*',
'*608*',
'*610*',
'*611*',
'*1212*',
'*603*',
'*604*'
)


$csv.Username | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ADUser $_ -Properties Department | Select-Object SamAccountName,Department
}
```

So far, this retrieves the expected data, as shown below

```
SamAccountName Department                              
-------------- ----------                              
user1          First floor department (0601)
user2          Second floor department (0609)                   
user3          Second floor department (0609)                   
user4          Second floor department (0609)                   
user5          Third floor department (0604)              
user6          Fourth floor department (0707)      
user7          Fifth floor department (0500)                  
user8          Sixth floor department (1306)   
user9          First floor department (0601)
```

But I want PowerShell to show me only those contained in `$IS`, something like

```
Get-ADUser $_ -Properties Department | Select-Object SamAccountName,Department Where-Object {Department -like $IS}
```

And the expected output would be

```
SamAccountName Department                              
-------------- ----------                              
user1          First floor department (0601)
user2          Second floor department (0609)                   
user3          Second floor department (0609)                   
user4          Second floor department (0609)                   
user5          Third floor department (0604)   
user9          First floor department (0601)
```

NOTE: `.csv` file contains 700,000+ rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Where-Object` *can* do this, but it isn't the best way. The way you're using `Get-ADUser` will retrieve *every* user in your domain. That's the part that will take the longest. So you don't want to retrieve any more users than you have to, since that will just waste your time.

Instead, use the `-Filter` parameter of `Get-ADUser` so you only ask AD for the users you want. In your case, you'd need a string like this:

```
Department -like *601*' -or Department -like '*609*' -or etc.
```

You can get a string like that from your array by doing this:

```
"Department -like '$($IS -Join "' -or Department -like '")'"
```

You can read about `-Join` in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_join?view=powershell-6).

But then you also can't use the `-Identity` parameter (which is what `$_` is being mapped to) at the same time you're using `-Filter`. So you'll have to include the username (or `SamAccountName`) in the filter.

Putting it together, this is what it would look like:

```bsh
$csv.Username | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$_' -and (Department -like '$($IS -Join "' -or Department -like '")')" -Properties Department | Select-Object SamAccountName,Department
}
```

Comment: I actually worked, I added some edits to your answer since 'Description' was incorrect.

Comment: @BryanArreola Whoops, sorry. I read too fast. There is an attribute called `Description`, it's just not the one you're looking for.